# Change back to Google classic calendar

Tags: google-calendar, user-interface

Google just reverted me to the new calendar. When I click on the gear, I don't have the "classic" option anymore. I hate the new format. Anyone have any ideas.

Comment: From my experience with Google, they might change it back if enough people complain, or at least put in an option to choose. But maybe, you get used to the new design faster than you think.

Comment: I've just updated my answer - Google removed the option also from their support page, and according to the G Suite announcements - since February 28th, it's permanent for all users.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE:**

**It's not possible.**

The [support](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/7541906) page (also mentioned in my original answer) was updated, the option to go back to classic is no longer written there, so it's not an option.
(Thanks for the comment [ale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale)).

And according to [this G Suite announcement](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/01/new-google-calendar-web-ui-to-begin.html):

> In this phase, users will still have the option to opt out of the new UI until February 28th, 2018, when all users will be fully upgraded.

---

It doesn't seems to be possible.

Have a look at this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/Jx_eUdJe1pE) where more people are angry about it.

According to [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/7541906) it says that there should be a button to go back to the classic one but since the button is no longer available, we can only assume that they don't want us to go back to the old one.

Comment: Google Support pages are often quite far behind when it comes to changes.

Comment: Thanks, I checked again and now it got updated - the option is no longer there, so it's really not possible anymore.

Comment: The biggest problem is this bug: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/r3OC4cL53NQ;context-place=topicsearchin/calendar/category$3Auser-interface-and-views

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot go back to the old Google Calendar.** Even if it is possible (which it's probably not), you will have to use this version in the end. It's like with the new Gmail: you can go back to the older version of Gmail but once the new version is official released to the public, you will no longer be able to go back to the older version.