# Color text for meetings in new Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Used to be that in the *Month* view of ("classic"?) Google Calendar an appointment's text would show up in (a shade of) the calendar's color. After the update to the new Google Calendar, from which [you can't seem to switch back anymore](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114429/19610), it looks like this:

[image: Calendar coloring]

Is there anyway to get the 'old' behavior back with a setting or some such, to make the texts appear in gray and blue, respectively? Or am I doomed to user scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no setting for that. It's possible that Google will add an option, since lots of people are complaining on [the Google Calendar help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/calendar), but I wouldn't hold your breath.

**There is a new browser extension** to change the event title colors, though.

[Chrome installation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gcalcolor/edegnmdhngniabdiiidplepangdoccna)

[Firefox installation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gcalcolor/)

[Project home on Github](https://github.com/adelespinasse/gcalcolor)

Full disclosure: extension was written by me.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Taught me a few new extension-writing-tips too :-)

Answer (score 0):

If someone would like to change the text settings for events in Google Calendar (the google search of which points to this thread) here is how to do:

Click on the cog for Settings menu

[image: Settings Menu]

Click Density and color

[image]

Then you will be able to select the old, black look:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't allow me to have differently colored text per calendar though, does it?

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to only apply for full-day events in the Month view and not appointments. I know you weren't asking for this specifically but at least it can offer partial remedy for some of us who wish the "old" look was better :)